# SSH Connection timed out when trying to reach Ubuntu Server through Windows 10 Command Prompt

Tags: ssh

Hello dear colleagues,

i tried everything to build a connection via SSH. Nevertheless i get the error message "ssh: connect to host x port 22: Connection timed out". I managed once to get it to the error message "ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.150 port 22: Connection refused" but i do not know what happened since than.

What i tried until now:

- Openssh-server is installed and updated
- Checked my Firewall on Ubuntu
- Checked if the username and IP Adress is correct
- My Service SSH Status is "active (running)
- My Windows Laptop has the optional feature "openssh server" and "openssh client"
- My Port 22 Server ist on "LISTEN"
- The Firewall for 22/tcp is on "ALLOW"
- My Firewall Policy is on "allow (incoming), allow(outgoing), disabled (routed). And all my Port 22/tcp are on "ALLOW IN"
- SSH is available on the remote server, when i run the command ssh localhost, everything works.
- And many more things i cannot recall..

I even cannot ping my Ubuntu Server anymore. Yesterday i was able to ping it but now not anymore. I can still ping it from my Ubuntu Server though. Now i get the error message "Answer from x: Destination Host unreachable".

I still can reach [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) when i ping it from my ubuntu server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is fail2ban installed?  Is there an application firewall on the windows side?

Comment: Just the normal Windows Firewall. I tried to deactivate it and tried and it than again but it did not work either. Did not restart though but i do not think that that was the problem.

Comment: Temporarily deactivating windows firewall is probably good enough for testing.  (Don't forget to reactivate it.)  If deactivating helps, you may need to edit the rules to add your application as allowed, otherwise it's a different problem.

Comment: If ping cannot reach that system: Wrong IP address or the system is on a different network.

Comment: Ping success is a good test.  Ping failure is not -- ping is very frequently firewalled, including by windows internal firewall.